# Role Based Custom Authorization for WebApi and MVC Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, asp.net-web-api

I am using mvc controller for login and webapi controller for REST operations.I need to authorize web api controllers based on the user roles that set while login. After searching long time I came to know we can use forms authentication. The problem I think is the value from cookie can access from different application also? How can we set `Iprinciple` values from mvc and access from webapi. Is it possible? If yes then, Can you provide any sample code?

Current Approach:

Setting cookie from MVC:

```
SessionWrapper.CustomPrincipalModel = customPrincipalModel;
            string userData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customPrincipalModel);

            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
              1, customPrincipalModel.LogonName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(8), false, userData);
            string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);

            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Read the cookie from webapi Filter Attribute.

```
var header = filterContext.Request.Headers.GetCookies(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
            if (header != null && header.Count > 0)
            {
                //// Take out the cookie 
                var authCookie = header.First().Cookies.First(one => one.Name == FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
                //// Create forms-authentication ticket based on the encrypted forms-authentication ticket. 
                var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
                if (ticket != null)
                {
                    //// Get the roles associated for the current user
                    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomPrincipalModel>(ticket.UserData);
                    CustomPrincipal principal = new CustomPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(result.LogonName), result.AccessLevels);
                    principal.CustomPrincipalModel = result;
                    this.CurrentUser = principal;
                }
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Roles))
            {
                if (this.CurrentUser.IsInRole(this.Roles))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use token based authentication for web api 
here is the link
http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/